# I have got this question as an array of array . But I am not quite sure what will be the output of the same

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, numpy-ndarray

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(9, dtype = "float").reshape(3,3)
ind1 = np.array([[1,2],[0,1]])
ind2 = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])

arr[ind1,ind2]
```

I understood why `arr[ind1]` displays what it displays and the same with `arr[ind2]`, but how to understand `arr[ind1,ind2]`?

I tried for understanding `arr[ind1]` and the same with `arr[ind2]` but what to do if there is a 2,2,3 matrix inside a 1,2 matrix and why is the output 2,2 matrix?

Comment: Come on, at least tell us the shapes of the alternatives, even if you are too lazy to actually show the results.  It's not like you're dealing with (100,100) shape arrays.

Comment: I would have done myself If I would have known...

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is just:
Print out the array like down below:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(9, dtype = "float").reshape(3,3)
ind1 = np.array([[1,2],[0,1]])
ind2 = np.array([[0,2],[1,2]])
print(arr[ind1,ind2])
```

Answer (score 0):

You are simply indexing the first and second dimension. Note that flattening the indexing arrays results in

```
>>> arr[ind1.flatten(),ind2.flatten()] 
array([3., 8., 1., 5.])
```

And since your indexing arrays are of shape (2, 2), you get a result of (2, 2).